# How to override chapter typesetting in table of content, using classicthesis?

Tags: classicthesis

I am using a template that was built based on [classicthesis](https://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis?lang=en).

I don't seem to be able to override the typesetting of *chapter titles* and a few other things.

In the figure below, you can see that "LIST OF FIGURES" and "INTRODUCTION" in my TOC are not normal *upper-case*, but maybe *small-caps*ed.

[image]

My attempt to override it (in preamble of [my main document](https://pastebin.com/rPemu8DU)) works for the actual chapter title, but not in TOC.

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\normalfont\normalsize}
```

Any ideas how I can override them with normal *upper-case*?

Comment: It's gonna be `\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\spacedallcaps}` or whatever you need; explained for the generic command `cftXaftersnumb` in the manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip , That was it! Thanks a lot. I would be more than happy to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\cftchapaftersnumb` controls how the chapter titles are typeset in the TOC, so if you want them in spaced all caps call

`\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\spacedallcaps}`

after the call to classicthesis.sty.

Details explained for the generic command `cftXaftersnumb` in the manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft